# Compare values ​between two object arrays

Tags: javascript

I have the following scenario:

```
var arr1 = [{
   sys_id: "b717af1adbd0bf00daba4410ba961913", 
   className: "x_rdbsa_cross_fert_cross_fertilization", 
   display_field: {display_value: "L190322025", label: "Number", type: "string", value: "L190322025"}, 
   secondary_fields: {display_value: "Waiting for Approval", label: "Status", type: "integer", value: "10"}];


var arr2 = [{approver: null, number: "L190322025-1", country: "Argentina", id: "0567a35adbd0bf00daba4410ba9619d6", state: "Waiting for Approval"}
```

I want to buy the arr2 number with the arr1 number display_field.display_value

Comment: Hey Daniel. Could you please give a sample output. It is not very clear as to what you actually need

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in your example (see below) so fix that first:

```js
var arr1 = [{
  sys_id: "b717af1adbd0bf00daba4410ba961913",
  className: "x_rdbsa_cross_fert_cross_fertilization",
  display_field: {
    display_value: "L190322025",
    label: "Number",
    type: "string",
    value: "L190322025"
  },
  secondary_fields: {
    display_value: "Waiting for Approval",
    label: "Status",
    type: "integer",
    value: "10"
  }
}]; // <----you forgot this closing curly brace


var arr2 = [{
  approver: null,
  number: "L190322025-1",
  country: "Argentina",
  id: "0567a35adbd0bf00daba4410ba9619d6",
  state: "Waiting for Approval"
}]

// Now compare the relevant properties of first object in each array
console.log(arr1[0].display_field.display_value === arr2[0].number) // false
```